# Dns response doesn't reach destination

Tags: python, python-2.7, dns, network-programming, pycharm

I'm trying to write my own dns server with python code. So, I send dns request from my computer to my gateway (which i get from ipconfig-> default gateway). The request reaches to my server and when I'm trying to response, it seems like the dns response not reaching the client destination (at this case my computer).
On the client i get "Standard query response Server failure" instead of regular dns response.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Client wireshark:
[image: client]
Server wireshark:
[image: sever]

Client code:

```
def ConvertToDnsNameFormat(name) :
    result = ""
    lock = 0
    name += "."
    length = len(name)
    for i in range(0, length) :
        if name[i] == "." :
            result += chr(i-lock)
            while lock < i :
                result += name[lock]
                lock = lock + 1
            lock = lock + 1
    result += (chr(0))
    return  result


hostname= "random1231.ns.cs.colman.ac.il"
hostname = ConvertToDnsNameFormat(hostname)
format = '!HHHHHH' + str(len(hostname)) + 'sHH' # the DNS query format
dnsMessage = pack(format, 1234, 256, 1, 0, 0, 0, hostname, 1, 1) # create the massage

#my gateway
HOST_IP = "192.168.1.1"
PORT = 53

AF = socket.AF_INET
TYPE = socket.SOCK_DGRAM
PROTO = socket.IPPROTO_UDP
mySocket = socket.socket(AF, TYPE, PROTO)

mySocket.sendto(dnsMessage, (HOST_IP, PORT))
(resp, address) = mySocket.recvfrom(1024)
```

Server code:
I took this code from [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/491264-mini-fake-dns-server/)

```
import socket

class DNSQuery:
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data=data
    self.dominio=''

    tipo = (ord(data[2]) >> 3) & 15   # Opcode bits
    if tipo == 0:                     # Standard query
      ini=12
      lon=ord(data[ini])
      while lon != 0:
        self.dominio+=data[ini+1:ini+lon+1]+'.'
        ini+=lon+1
        lon=ord(data[ini])

  def respuesta(self, ip):
    packet=''
    if self.dominio:
      packet+=self.data[:2] + "\x81\x80"
      packet+=self.data[4:6] + self.data[4:6] + '\x00\x00\x00\x00'   # Questions and Answers Counts
      packet+=self.data[12:]                                         # Original Domain Name Question
      packet+='\xc0\x0c'                                             # Pointer to domain name
      packet+='\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x3c\x00\x04'             # Response type, ttl and resource data length -> 4 bytes
      packet+=str.join('',map(lambda x: chr(int(x)), ip.split('.'))) # 4bytes of IP
    return packet

if __name__ == '__main__':
  ip='192.168.1.1'
  print 'pyminifakeDNS:: dom.query. 60 IN A %s' % ip

  udps = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
  udps.bind(('10.10.250.40',53))

  try:
    while 1:
      data, addr = udps.recvfrom(1024)
      p=DNSQuery(data)
      udps.sendto(p.respuesta(ip), addr)
      print 'Respuesta: %s -> %s' % (p.dominio, ip)
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'Finalizando'
    udps.close()
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because the server *is* failing. Try to do a ping to random1231.ns.cs.colman.ac.il, you'll see that with that domain, the response is server failure:

[image]

So, the miniDNS program is not capturing the DNS requests. Did you try installing it on your localhost address? (127.0.0.1, say port 4567) and configure your DNS service to that address.

Comment: Maybe you tried when the server code wasnt on. I tried to ping something like 1111.ns.cs.colman.ac.il and the server send this packet. http://s16.postimg.org/ofvq4yoph/pinganswer.png